# how to change EditText bottom line programmatically

Tags: java, android, xml, android-activity

I have the activity in which I bundle data to another activity. With that data I also bundle a custom color that I would like to have bottom line of EditText shown in activity 2.

Activity 1:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putExtra("Color", color);
```

Activity 2:

```
int value = getIntent().getExtras().getInt(Color)
```

Now, can I change the color of EditText programmatically when I get the bundle from activity 1? If you can help me with that I would be really grateful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Might be something like,

Activity 2//

```
int value = getIntent().getExtras().getInt(Color);
// Here I assume you have defined edittext form layout file so it is not null
editText.getBackground().setColorFilter(value, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

Try this and let me know, It works or not.

Answer (score -1):

Activity 1

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);
Bundle bundle  = new Bundle();
bundle.putInt("Color", color); //Your id
intent.putExtras(bundle); //Put your id to your next Intent
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Activity 2

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
int value = b.getInt("Color");
```